# Parsing firewall rules in Python

Tags: python

I am writing a script to parse firewall rules from the configuration of a Cisco ASA.

Examples of my input include:

```
access-list myACL line 1 extended permit tcp host 10.8.13.200 host 10.32.53.22 eq 1122
access-list myACL line 2 extended permit tcp 10.8.13.0 255.255.255.0 host 10.1.206.17 eq 445 
access-list myACL line 3 extended permit udp host 10.8.13.200 eq 54345 host 10.1.206.17 eq 445
access-list myACL line 4 extended permit icmp any any
```

My desired output, in the form of a .csv, for the three lines above would be the following. However, these could just as well be tuples to be stored in a database.

```
#aclName,lineNumber,action,protocol,sourceIP,sourcePort,destIP,destPort
myACL,1,permit,tcp,10.8.13.200,*,10.32.53.22,1122
myACL,2,permit,tcp,10.8.13.0/24,*,10.1.206.17,445
myACL,3,permit,udp,10.8.13.200,54345,10.1.206.17,445
myACL,4,permit,icmp,*,*,*,*
```

I'm having trouble choosing an approach to this project. I've looked at many options including ats, shlex, or even just using a regex, but I'm having difficulty determining what the best option is. Would PLY help here?

What would be a suitable approach for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first 6 fields seem to be quite predictable, that leaves the endpoint which can have several representations. A possibility would be (untested code, but I hope you get the idea):

```
parts = rule.split(" ")
aclName, _, lineNumber, _, action, protocol = parts[:6]
endpoints = parts[6:]

def get_endpoint(eps):
    host, port = "*", "*"
    if eps[0] == "host":
        host = eps[1]
        eps = eps[2:]
    elif eps[0] == "any":
        eps = eps[1:]
    else:
        host = eps[0] + "/" + mask_to_bits(eps[1])
        eps = eps[2:]

    if eps and eps[0] == 'eq':
        port = eps[1]
        eps = eps[2:]
    return host, port, eps

sourceIP, sourcePort, endpoints = get_endpoint(endpoints)
destIP, destPort, endpoints = get_endpoint(endpoints)
```

Comment: This is excellent - thanks so much for a quick reply. This does the trick, and doesn't require me working on a parser!

Answer (score 0):

If the need is to just output a CSV target, I suggest whichever approach you are most familiar with. If it's a one-time/ad-joc thing, I further recommend whatever allows you todo it the fastest.

If it were me -- I'd probably regex.

Answer (score 0):

I would parse the firewall string with `.split(" ")`